# Hausdorff Dimension of a k-dimensional submanifold, hence $L^n(M) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, lebesgue-measure

If $M \in P(R^n)$ is a k-dimensional submanifold, show that the Hausdorff-Dimension of M is k.

Also, is there a quicker/easier way to show, that $L^n(M) = 0$, where L is the Lebesgue-Measurement.

Comment: What is $P(R^n)$?

Comment: As for a quick proof, just recall that measure 0 sets under a $C^1$ function are mapped to measure 0 sets, and you know a $k$-plane has $n$-measure 0.